# How can i set current date, as a database table name in sqlite?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-studio

I'm trying to create a table that name is the current date.

**Here is my table name that i try**

```
 static String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dmmmyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());


public static String table_name=date;
```

**but it has shown this error**

```
unrecognized token: "26_10_2018" (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO 26_10_2018(quentity_cl,price_cl,item_Cl,spinner_cl) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
```

My aim is to set a table name using the current date.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you could base what you want on the following, which get's around the fact that tables names (and names overall column's triggers ....) cannot, unless enclosed, start with numbers amongst other restrictions [SQL As Understood By SQlite - SQLite Keywords](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html):-

```
public class DBHelperNewtablePerDay extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "mydb";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    public static final String COL_DAILY_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COl_DAILY_DATA = "_data";
    SQLiteDatabase mDB;
    private String mTodaysTable;

    DBHelperNewtablePerDay(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        createTodaysTable();
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }

    private void createTodaysTable() {
        String table_name = "[" + dateTodayinDD_MM_YYFormat() + "]";
        Cursor csr = mDB.query("sqlite_master",null,"name=?",new String[]{table_name},null,null,null);
        if (csr.getCount() < 1) {
            mDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + table_name + "(" +
                    COL_DAILY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                    COl_DAILY_DATA + " TEXT " +
                    ")");
        }
        mTodaysTable = table_name;
    }

    private String dateTodayinDD_MM_YYFormat() {
        return  new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    }

    public String getTodaysTableName() {
        return mTodaysTable;
    }
}
```

- Obviosuly the column names would likely need to be adjusted accordingly.
- Note the `getTodaysTableName` method that returns the current day's table.

  ### - Note the corrected format

## Disclaimer

### This answer is in no means advocating/recommending the practice of creating tables on a daily basis.

Answer (score 1):

Table names **cannot begin with a number**,you could replace with:

```
String tableName = "[26_10_2018]"
```

Comment: Yes. Columns as well cannot start with a number.

Comment: how i do it dynamic?

I want to make a table every day.

Comment: To @navylover: I have voted down your answer because it is simply wrong; table names *can* begin with a number, but must be quoted when they are referenced.  That said, I will say to the OP, if you think you want to create a table for each date, your database design almost certainly needs to be redesigned.  (So don't do that!)

Comment: @ImranSk I'd advise ignoring the order to not do it. However, rather consider that there may well be a better design, such as having a column that includes the date. It's unlikely that efficiency would be an issue, using a single table, until the table is getting many thousands of rows and capability wise a table can have up to 9223372036854775807 rows (double if you tweak things to handle negative values).